# How to load fixture dataset for integration test in spring data neo4j (SDN5)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to write integration tests in a project which uses spring data neo4j version 5 (SDN5) in context of a (non-web) spring boot application. For the integration tests I would like to import a defined dataset before each test to get a initial starting point (fixture) of the graph-db, but I don't know how to load it. Does someone know how to do it?

I'm using neo4j 3.4.3, SDN5, Spring Boot 2.0, JUnit 5.1.

I get integration tests in general to run and execute against an embedded instance via

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataNeo4jTest(
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
        type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ApplicationRunner.class
    )
)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {TransformationService.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class Neo4jAgentAutomatonTest {
  @Test
  void getStates() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: [NoSQL-Unit](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit) will not work as it is not really compatible with [neo4j v3+](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit/issues/174) or [JUnit 5](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit/issues/175)

Answer (score 0):

a) When you also add `neo4j-ogm-test` to your project it provides you the `TestUtils` class.
This class has the method `readCQLFile` that parses the file and returns the cypher query.

b) You could also read the file on your own without this dependency.

In the end you add a `SessionFactory` dependency as autowired in your class and execute the resulting query

```
class Test {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.query(               
         TestUtils.readCQLFile("<filePath>").toString(), emptyMap());
    // ....
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I get a CQL file dump from an existing DB that I can than import with the TestUtils?

Comment: Ok. Did not get that it is a full database you are talking about but was thinking about a test set of data. I never worked with a cypher dump tool but you could try this: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-export